# Getting totals of columns depending on other column values

Tags: windows, excel

I have an Excel sheet as follows:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
------------------------------
MyCorp   | 23.30    | 13.00
Acme     | 99.40    | 10.85
Acme     | 11.30    | 61.80
Acme     | 1.99     | 2.00
Acme     | 24.85    | 14.76
NewBiz   | 11.00    | 15.00
NewBiz   | 44.00    | 44.22
```

I have several hundred of these records and would like to get summaries (totals) of column B and C for each Column A (company name) - taking into account if there is more than one record for a company the totals should be added

How could this be accomplished within Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this layout, I believe the quickest approach would be to select another cell to output the data to and choose *Consolidate* from the *data tab*, with the settings shown...

[image]

... alternatively add column titles and use a Pivot Table which would offer more flexibility.